# Why do my rockets sometimes go haywire?

Tags: half-life-2

For some reason, my rockets sometimes fail to hit the drop ship I'm aiming at, which can be a problem because it requires a full set of 3 rockets to take one down. How do I prevent the rockets from falling off course? I know that I have to keep the lazer on the ship, but is the drop ship somehow deflecting them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is the drop ship somehow deflecting them?

Yes, drop-ships will shoot at oncoming missiles, which will cause the missile to go haywire and miss.

You can avoid the bullets by firing away from the dropship and then directing the missile back into it (sometimes I simply use a slight spiral).